# C++ : Interix signals

Tags: c++, posix, compiler-errors, signals, interix

How to **compile**/ use **signals** on the **Interix** platform? I am unable to get it to compile because Interix appears to be **non-POSIX compliant**, at least in its implementation of **`signal.h`**.

If anyone has found a way to work around this and allow code with signals to compile on Interix, please do let me know how!

Thanks.

---

#### Details:

Legacy software in C, C++, and is built on Linux and Interix (for Win XP).

Am getting the following errors during compilation, on Interix only; not on Linux, after adding `pthread` and `signal` code. Cannot use `pthreads` without signals because conflicts with Xmotif (compiles but crashes at run time).

errors due to struct differences:

```
`struct siginfo' has no member named `si_value'
aggregate `sigval val' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
`struct sigaction' has no member named `sa_sigaction'
```

errors due to undeclared:

```
`sigqueue' undeclared
`SA_NODEFER' undeclared
`SA_SIGINFO' undeclared
```

---

#### Other material consulted:

http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-gnulib@gnu.org/msg10425.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/gnulib/signal_002eh.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interix
http://www.opengroup.org/susv3xbd/signal.h.html

Comment: @Alexandre C. : nfortunately, it is stipulated by the customer's requirements/deployment environment. Would love to switch to mingw or cygwin if we could decide!

Comment: oh, good luck then, especially with pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

According to the POSIX specification, there `struct sigaction` has no member `sa_sigaction`, it has `sa_handler`.

- POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html
- Interix: http://www.suacommunity.com/man/2/sigaction.2.html

Interix is POSIX compliant in the case, the code you are porting is not.

Note that Linux can be made to work with `sa_handler`.

You may be able to get it work using the correct `#DEFINE`s though.

Comment: I see an sa_sigaction member listed in the specifications on the POSIX page you linked to.

sa_handler is supposed to be used when the SA_SIGINFO flag is not set. If that flag is set, then sigaction.sa_sigaction is a pointer to the handler function, or filled with the macro that defines the action.

Comment: @BraedenP, OK yeah, not sure how I made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Interix man page](http://www.suacommunity.com/man/2/sigaction.2.html) and the open group link above.

You can possibly replace the si_sigaction with sa_handler.